# Why does Syndra see such popularity in recent pro play?

Tags: league-of-legends

Syndra really got a mid lane revival in LCS for apparently no reason. No changes to the champion (since mid season mage update), no changes to her items.

Is there a determinable reason for that phenomenon or is it just that someone re-discovered her strength?

Answer (score 1):

Just because that champion didn't receive changes doesn't mean other champions didn't. A number of mid laners that have been popular throughout the split were nerfed.

The LCS is currently being played on [Patch 6.15](http://eune.leagueoflegends.com/en/news/game-updates/patch/patch-615-notes#patch-champions) which saw a ton of small balance changes to a number of champions. Nerfed mid laners include:

- Karma (possible flex pick mid)
- Malzahar
- Taliyah
- Viktor
- Vladimir

Syndra has been seen as slightly under the top tier of mid laners. Bringing down a number of these top tier mids evens out the playing field a bit which was the intention of the 6.15 patch.

Also good to know is that since she hasn't seen much (if any) play since the mid-season update it's likely that many people aren't used to playing against her. Though this can also work against the player using Syndra since they won't be as practiced either.

Comment: That sounds actually pretty plausible. So it's in part the classic "previously another champion filled that role slightly better".

Comment: That's part of it. If you look at what Syndra's kit does it has long range pick and ability to decimate a single target with her ultimate. Sort of similar to Malzahar and/or Viktor in those ways.